# Upgrading MariaDB on AWS Linux machine

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, mariadb, moodle

I have a moodle site which runs on a linux AWS box and I'm trying to upgrade it.  I need to have MariaDB 10.3 on there, and I currently have 10.2.10

I've followed the instruction for upgrading using yum from this webpage https://www.ryadel.com/en/mariadb-10-upgrade-10-3-without-losing-data-how-to/ and all goes fine until I get to Running Transaction Check and Running Transaction Check at which point I get the following

```
Transaction check error:
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of MariaDB-common-10.3.27-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file fr
om package mariadb-config-3:10.2.10-2.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18 from install of MariaDB-compat-10.3.27-1.el7.centos.x86_64 co
nflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-3:10.2.10-2.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
```

I'm not sure what to do now?  Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EC2 is not designed for database specifically

You seem to be installing and running your database on EC2 (what you call a `linux AWS box`), this means you can SSH into the instance and install software manually and carry out updates and edit configuration files and settings etc.

### RDS is designed for Database

RDS also has other really convenient features like automatic version upgrade and maintenance window management.

If your situation allows I would suggest to use a tool designed for database instead of having to configure things manually. It will save you a lot of time and troubleshooting, it is also more secured.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for that.  I did look at moving to RDS but its super expensive for what we are doing.

Comment: t3.micro RDS instances should be very affordable. Are you running test or production workload?

Comment: I'm running a production Virtual Learning Environment with about 3000 users mostly accessing from 8am until about 11pm with cron tasks and backups done overnight

Comment: OK I worked with AWS EC2 and RDS for over 6 years now, if you have few thousand users, it really isn't that expensive compared to running EC2. If you factor in the labour cost of upgrading maintaining and backing up the DB, RDS overall is actually cheaper because you and your team spend less time fiddling with DB settings and manual snapshots. Investigate about it, I strongly recommend it, and I believe you will arrive at the same conclusion.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. There's nothing wrong or unusual about installing a database on EC2.